# jquery gallery with authentication

Tags: jquery, image, authentication, gallery

I would like to set up a web site with a photo gallery where users can download only their pictures after they log in. At first I used [FileThingie](http://www.solitude.dk/filethingie/) as a file manager which does basically what I need.

A new requirements says that previews of the pictures should be shown and I think that doesn't work with the file manager script.

So I would like to know if there is gallery script or plugin where users can watch and download only photos meant for them. I don't want to use Wordpress or any CMS if possible.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Frank

Answer (score 0):

It is nearly impossible to create a safe gallery without any script-language like PHP or Ruby (...). You can hide the file, but an intelligent user will find it, if he want. You need a server based security for this kind of gallery.

An pure javascript solution could be to name the files after a key, which only the user knows. But this is, if you had have a lot pictures, hard work.

Example: 
You have an User with his secret key "iLikeMumy". Now you can create files like this:

```
Image orignal: holiday.jpg
Rename it to: holiday_f4c46e7ae9591b4c96c235f12e558e4211a0923f.jpg
```

Here is an example:
http://jsfiddle.net/Vh253/

The script change the filesnames from the original to the original+key. 
(I included an sha1-hashing Library)